# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec looses/changes some parameters

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

( `-Dexec.mainClass=maven.MainClass` becomes `maven.MainClass`. )

When executing Java class using maven from within Java ([Eclipse plugin actualy](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.maven))
`-Dexec.mainClass=maven.MainClass` becomes `maven.MainClass`

```
package maven;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("app is running!");
    }
}
```

from Eclipse using

```
    Process p = DebugPlugin.exec(cmds, workingPath, envp);
    RuntimeProcess process = (RuntimeProcess)DebugPlugin.newProcess(launch, p, MavenConstants.PROCESS_MESSAGE);
```

that `p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine, envp);` just calls Java

```
 p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine, envp);
```

And array of strings that concatenated looks like string below, somehow looses `-Dexec.mainClass=` part.

```
D:\Code\springsource\3.0\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\mvn.bat compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=maven.MainClass
```

output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building org.example.maven 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.672s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 24 23:59:50 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "maven.MainClass". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

but from cmd shell using `mvn` or full filename is OK

```
D:\Progs\Enide-Monster-08-kepler-win32\runtime-EclipseApplication\org.example.maven>mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=maven.MainClass
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building org.example.maven 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ org.example.maven ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ org.example.maven ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ org.example.maven >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ org.example.maven <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ org.example.maven ---
app is running!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.342s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 24 23:56:41 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


D:\Progs\Enide-Monster-08-kepler-win32\runtime-EclipseApplication\org.example.maven>D:\Code\springsource\3.0\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\mvn.bat compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=maven
.MainClass
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building org.example.maven 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ org.example.maven ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ org.example.maven ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ org.example.maven >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ org.example.maven <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ org.example.maven ---
app is running!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.435s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 24 23:57:46 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that `cmdLine.add("-Dmaven.test.skip=true");` also becomes just `true` with similar error.

I notices no mention in JavaDoc of this behavior for `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(`

Solved by putting all option in one string.

```
    cmdLine.add(mavenPath);
    cmdLine.add(mavenOptions+" compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="+packageClass);
```