# Java - process launched with Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cannot create temp file

Tags: java, exec, nodeclipse, enide

process launched with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine, envp, workingDirectory);` cannot create temp file.

It is used inside [Maven plugin for Eclipse](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.maven)

Quote from `mvn` launched:

```
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: �ܾ���ʡ�
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1879)
```

[Full log](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/120)

This is not Maven related as [Gradle has the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260657/eclipse-plugin-development-gradle-fails-to-run-from-eclipse-launcher-java-io)

[Demo piece of code](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.maven/docs/MediocreExecMaven.java) runs into the same error.

```
        String mavenPath = "D:\\Progs\\springsource\\apache-maven-3.0.4\\bin\\mvn.bat";
        String mavenOptions  = "-X compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=runclass.Runme";

        String[] cmdLine = new String[2];
        cmdLine[0] = mavenPath;  //cmdLine.add(mavenPath);
        cmdLine[1] = mavenOptions;      //cmdLine.add(mavenOptions+" compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="+packageClass);        

        String[] envp = new String[2];
        //Map<String, String> envm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        envp[0] = "JAVA_HOME=" + System.getProperty("java.home"); //System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
        envp[1] = "M2_HOME=" + System.getenv("MAVEN_HOME");     

        File workingDirectory = null;
        String currentDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
        log(currentDir);
        String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir"); //User working directory ; "user.home"     User home directory
        workingDirectory = new File(userDir);       
        log(workingDirectory.toString());

        //
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(cmdLine, envp, workingDirectory);
        InputStream stdout = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdout);
        InputStreamReader isr2 = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(isr2);
```

Update:

Passing TMP and TEMP environment variables does not help.
Passing  `null` instead of `envp` also does not help.

> If envp is null, the subprocess inherits the environment settings of the current process.

Comment: Beware, that each element in `cmdLine` is expected to be a individual argument passed to the first element in `cmdLine` (ie `cmdline[0]` is the command to executes, all other elements are individual arguments). Right now, you `bat` file is receiving a single argument, which I doubt is what you want ;)

Comment: I am quite aware of that. This is done on purpose, otherwise there is some undocumented handling of "a=b" string (just becomes "b"). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358548/java-runtime-getruntime-exec-looses-changes-some-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by passing a set of environment variables.